# How to add Authentication to my proxy service(get) in wso2 esb(4.6.0)please any one help me the procedure,i cant find much more on this?

Tags: wso2-esb

These are the below proxy service and sequences...if i am running with empty curl command data is showing for get service,so that i want to authenticate that data

```
 <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Get_meter_Mobile" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence onError="fault">
         <property name="CONTENT_TYPE" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <payloadFactory>
            <format>
               <mmeter xmlns=""/>
            </format>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send receive="Get_meter_Mobile_seq">
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:9764/services/meter_DataService/" format="soap11"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
         <property name="ERROR_MESSAGE" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="ERROR_CODE" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <property name="CONTENT_TYPE" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achice this by applying POX security to your Proxy service. The blog post [1] will show you the steps to follow.

[1]. http://evanthika.blogspot.com/2012/12/pox-security-with-wso2-esb-proxy.html

Thank You,
Dharshana.